# Why would a star’s position in the sky change relative to another star right next to it?

Tags: star-systems

I'm curious about stars and I am wondering why a star would change its position in the sky due to another star right next to it?

Comment: "due to" - do you mean that another star is influencing it?

Comment: Yes that is what i meant to say

Comment: Still not clear what you mean. Do you mean the relative positions of two stars you can actually see in the sky? Or do you mean a pair of stars that can be separated with a telescope?

Comment: Is this something you've actually observed? If so, please update your question with the details.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at a planet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is gravity.

Stars have a lot of mass so there for there gravity is strong.

If 1 star gets close to another star that has slightly more mass this would mean that it gets pulled in. As a result the orbit would change.

**Edit**

This does not affect all stars due to the distance they are from each other. Usually if it affects start it is in binary systems.

Thanks to `Joan.bdm` for this.

Comment: I don't really think Username123 talks about binary systems. He/She is probably refering to stars that "seem to be close to each other" from our point of view but they are so far that gravity effect between them is negible.

Comment: I thought gravity would have affected it anyway. It is the gravity from the sun which keeps all our planets in orbit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Gravity between stars affect their motion, but most of the stars we see in the sky although they seem to be so close from our point of view they are too far to be affected from one to the other. But you are right, some of them, the closest ones, are affected by gravity. For example in some binary systems you'll see 1 or 2 stars depending on their relative position. Actually all stars are in motion, but they are so far  this movement is only visible in long terms.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I have edited my answer. Could you make sure that I got what you meant please?